# Get the a specific image from the post gallery linked to post_id

Tags: gallery

Is it possible to get the second image from the gallery with the `post_id`?

I usually work with `get_the_post_thumbnail` but in this case I would like to get the second image from the post gallery, so a different image from the post's featured image.

Does exist some tutorial to get it?

Comment: When you say a specific image, what do you mean?

Comment: I've fixed the question

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the images associated with a post with the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent'    => $post_parent_id // you'll need to set this somewhere else
);
$images = get_children( $args )
```

To go from that to the 2nd image, you should just need to point to `$images[1]`, but I'm not sure how that'd work, you might needa mess with the sort order a little.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll take a look as soon as possible!

Comment: Gallery is sorted by `menu_order` assuming the end user has dragged the attachments around (and saved) -- otherwise, they'll be in the order in which they were uploaded. Maybe adding `'orderby' => 'menu_order'` will help, @vittorio.